# Определить переменную по ее имени в виде строки

Tags: c#, .net

Можно ли как-то определить переменную по ее имени в виде строки?

Например:

```
int s = 0;
FindVar("s") = 25;
Console.WriteLine(s.ToString()); // 25
```

Знаю, что **функцию** можно, но вот именно переменная интересует.

Comment: мне кажется нет, так как функция - часть метаданных, то есть часть типа, который хранится в памяти. А переменная - это просто именованная ссылка на участок памяти, её название нигде не хранится

Comment: @tym32167 а как тогда компилятор понимает, что в данной области кода такая переменная уже существует, и не дает создавать повторно? не ужеле это просто строковая обработка?

Comment: Так компилятор это и понимает, но во время выполнения уже ничего не найти. Если вас интересует какая-то фишка C# типа `nameof(...)` то такого аналога для вашего вопроса нет.

Comment: Нет, нельзя - имена локальных переменных не переживают компиляцию. Т.е. на выходе будет одинаковый IL код для названия переменной `s`, и для такого же исходника, но с переменной `q`.

Comment: всем спасибо за внимание. жаль конечно...но ладно

Comment: Если переменную сделать полем/свойством класса, то до нее можно будет добраться через рефлексию и, в том числе, установить ей значение

Comment: @Андрей NOP через fieldinfo?

Comment: Да, получаете через `GetField()` экземпляр `FieldInfo` и делаете с ним всё что нужно

Comment: @Андрей  NOP Спасибо, можете ответом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С локальной переменной этого не сделать, т. к. компилятор имеет право вообще не использовать никакие переменные или назначить им свои имена.

Если вы сделаете переменную членом класса — полем или свойством, то задача станет решаемой: до членов класса можно добраться с помощью рефлексии:

```
class Data
{
    public int a, b, c;

    public void SetField(string name, int value)
    {
        var field = typeof(Data).GetField(name);
        field.SetValue(this, value);
    }
}
```

Затем:

```
var data = new Data();
Console.WriteLine(data.a); // 0
data.SetField("a", 10);
Console.WriteLine(data.a); // 10
```

Answer (score -2):

Можно.
Используйте Dictionary.

```
//Заполнение:
Dictionary<string, object> vars = new Dictionary<string, object>();
vars["переменная1"] = 20;
vars["переменная2"] = "Hello, world";
//Вывод:
Console.WriteLine(vars["переменная1"]); //20
Console.WriteLine(vars["переменная2"]); //Hello, world!
```